# useGetMany - fetches data by sending traction but does not update data field - code copied and used from react-admin document

Tags: react-admin

I had used the useGetMany to get topics for mathpapers. I can see based on reference the getMany
Tracation goes and fetch data as shown in console.log response. But the data is not stored in the
" const { data, loaded, error } - as it shows array of same size but undefined objects in console.log prints."
Please suggest what I am missing here.

```
const Mysubtopics = ({ record }: any) => {
    console.log(record);
    const subtopicsIds = record.subtopic_id;
    console.log('subtopicsID', subtopicsIds);
    const { data, loaded, error } = useGetMany('subtopics', subtopicsIds);
    //if (error) return <Error />;

    if (error) return <span>Error</span>;
    if (!loaded) return <span>Loading</span>;
    if (!data) return null;
    console.log('data', data);
    const allsubtopics = data.reduce((acc, subtopic) => {
        acc = acc.concat(subtopic.name.en);
        return acc;
    }, '');
    return (
        <span>
            {allsubtopics}
            {record.id}
        </span>
    );
};

const MathPaperList = (props: any) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const isSmall = useMediaQuery((theme: Theme) =>
        theme.breakpoints.down('sm')
    );
    return (
        <List
            {...props}
            filters={<MathPaperFilter />}
            sort={{ field: 'generated_at', order: 'DESC' }}
            exporter={exporter}
        >
            {isSmall ? (
                <SimpleList
                    primaryText={record => record.title}
                    secondaryText={record => <Mysubtopics record={record} />}
                    tertiaryText={record =>
                        new Date(record.generated_at).toLocaleDateString()
                    }
                />
            ) : ...........some more for desktop error is in above secondaryText.
```

I can see the following console.log -

```
    getMany subtopics {"ids":[10,12,14,3,5,8,1,2,4]}
index.js:31 
Object
data: Array(9)
0: {id: 1, name: {…}}
1: {id: 2, name: {…}}
2: {id: 3, name: {…}}
3: {id: 4, name: {…}}
4: {id: 5, name: {…}}
5: {id: 8, name: {…}}
6: {id: 10, name: {…}}
7: {id: 12, name: {…}}
8: {id: 14, name: {…}}
length: 9
Object
index.js:30 getMany subtopics {"ids":[10,12,14,3,5,8,1,2,4]}
MathPaperList.tsx:137 {id: 3, title: "3rd test for batch 2:30", batch_id: 1, subtopic_id: Array(3), generated_at: Thu Dec 30 2021 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), …}
MathPaperList.tsx:139 subtopicsID (3) [10, 12, 14]
MathPaperList.tsx:146 data (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
MathPaperList.tsx:137 {id: 2, title: "2nd test for batch 2:30", batch_id: 1, subtopic_id: Array(3), generated_at: Sat Dec 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), …}
MathPaperList.tsx:139 subtopicsID (3) [3, 5, 8]
MathPaperList.tsx:146 data (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
    __proto__: ...
    .........
```

Here is data.tsx

```
mathpapers: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: '1st test for batch 2:30',
        batch_id: 1,
        subtopic_id: [1, 2, 4],
        generated_at: new Date('2020-12-06'),
        difficulty: 80,
        mark1q: 0,
        mark2q: 5,
        mark3q: 0,
        mark4q: 6,
        mark5q: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: '2nd test for batch 2:30',
        batch_id: 1,
        subtopic_id: [3, 5, 8],
        generated_at: new Date('2020-12-26'),
        difficulty: 40,
        mark1q: 3,
        mark2q: 0,
        mark3q: 4,
        mark4q: 3,
        mark5q: 2,
    },
    ..... 
],
subtopics: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: { en: 'Sport' },
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: { en: 'Technology' },
    },
    ..... 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the missing part, which is never documented in the react-admin was you need to have resourses in the App.tsx file to hook up the resource to get data, so need below 2 resource lines with subtopics in the App.tsx -

```
import subtopics from './subtopics';
.....

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Admin
            title=""
            dataProvider={dataProvider}
            customReducers={{ theme: themeReducer }}
            customRoutes={customRoutes}
            authProvider={authProvider}
            dashboard={Dashboard}
            loginPage={Login}
            layout={Layout}
            i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
            disableTelemetry
        >
            <Resource name="mathpapers" {...mathpapers} />
            <Resource name="subtopics" {...subtopics} />
            {/*<Resource
```

subtopics file is :

```
export default {

};
```